# Save Boolean result from Direct comparison in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to save the result of a comparison, inside a variable.

Instead of using (IF X = 1 BEGIN @Cond_JaCadastrado = 1 END), I would like to do as the example below .. But I am not finding a solution.

anyone know how to proceed?
[image: Comparition]

Comment: Rewrite the title of this question in english and post code as text not as an image

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: i've rewrited the question title. Sorry about this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign the result of a boolean expression to a variable as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so you need to use bitwise operators and you should use `ISNULL()` instead of `IS NULL`. `ISNULL()` takes a second parameter to use if the first parameter is null, set this to 0 or 1 depending if you want to check for `NOT IS NULL` or `IS NULL` respectively. In the example below I use the [bitwise operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `&` instead of `AND` or `&&` to make the expression return a integer value and not a boolean

```
DECLARE @var1 BIT
DECLARE @var2 BIT
DECLARE @result BIT
SET @var1 = (SELECT ...)
SET @var2 = (SELECT ...)
SET @result = (ISNULL(@var1, 0) & ISNULL(@var2, 0))
```

So in the above code if either `@var1` or `@var2` is null then `@result` will be false, same goes if either is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure understood your query well but you can use `CASE WHEN`

```
Set @Cond_Veh_Part = (SELECT 
                        CASE WHEN @VEHKEY IS NOT NULL 
                                AND @PARTKEY IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                      END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`

```
if  exists(select Veh_Key from KD_Veh where Veh_Cod = @VehCod)
    and exists (select Part_Key from KD_Part where Part_Cod = @PartCod)
set @Cond_Veh_Part = 1
else 
set  @Cond_Veh_Part = 0
```

Then you can use this variable.

```
If @Cond_Veh_Part = 1
Begin
—do something
End
If @Cond_Veh_Part = 2
Begin
—do something 
End
```

Comment: i want to resume all the syntax... in instead of use the IF clausule,.. i intend to assign the comparison result direct into my variable

Comment: The comparison result is assigned to your variable. I don't understand what else you want

Comment: ok.. I know that the result is assigned to my variable.. But i want to do all this stuff like this: @ var = (1 = 1 and 2 = 2) (That will assign a "True" value to my Var "@ var")

Then in My IF's i can do: 
IF @var 
begin
... code here
end